# How to run maven web application with jetty server in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jetty

I have to created maven project to run with jetty server this project is comfortably running using command line the same project if going to run in eclipse project getting build failure whats the problem

**Error**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.910 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-06T15:58:41+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/204M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\abc\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.infonex.edunex</groupId>
    <artifactId>school-managment-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>school-management</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <servlet.port>8080</servlet.port>
        <jersey.version>2.25.1</jersey.version>
        <struts2.version>2.3.14.3</struts2.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <sl4j.version>1.7.2</sl4j.version>
        <hsqldb.version>2.2.9</hsqldb.version>
        <mysql.connector.java.version>5.1.25</mysql.connector.java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>wso2</id>
            <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- other dependencies-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/captcha.simplecaptcha/simplecaptcha -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>captcha.simplecaptcha</groupId>
            <artifactId>simplecaptcha</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-excelant -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.19</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.5</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- end other dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-dojo-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-embeddedjsp-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jfreechart-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
            <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Struts 2 + Spring 3 need this jar, ContextLoaderListener -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Struts 2 + Spring integration plugins -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mockito -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.17.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.java.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- h2 database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.172</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.v201112011016</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail.glassfish</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.v201005082020</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey core Servlet 2.x implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey JSON Jackson (2.x) entity providers support module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalClasspathElements>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>test/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                        </additionalClasspathElements>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <configuration>
                            <properties>
                                <cargo.servlet.port>${servlet.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                        <deployables>
                            <!--
                              The project's artifact is automatically deployed if no deployable
                              is defined. However, we define it here so that we can specify the
                              context (we don't want the version to be included in the context).
                              -->
                            <deployable>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <properties>
                                    <context>${project.artifactId}</context>
                                </properties>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                    <dependencies>
                        <!-- specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                            <version>${mysql.connector.java.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>

                    <configuration>
                        <driver>org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/cookbook</url>
                        <username>root</username>
                        <password>root</password>
                        <srcFiles>
                          <srcFile>src/test/resources/schema.sql</srcFile>
                          <srcFile>src/test/resources/test-data.sql</srcFile>
                        </srcFiles>
                        <!--all executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true-->
                        <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>

                    </configuration>

                    <executions>

                        <!--  It creates integration test data before running the tests -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>create-integration-test-data</id>
                            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
                                <fileset>
                                    <basedir>/</basedir>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>schema.sql</include>
                                        <include>test-data.sql</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </fileset>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.2.v20120308</version> -->
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jettyXml>src/main/resources/jetty/jetty.xml</jettyXml>
                    <stopKey/>
                    <stopPort/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>perform-integration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>servlet.port</name>
                                    <value>${servlet.port}</value>
                                </property>
                            </systemProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify-integration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-cargo</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-cargo</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command from the same folder as your pom.xml file

`mvn jetty:run`

This starts Jetty and serves up your project on http://localhost:8080/.

Jetty will continue to run until you stop it. While it runs it periodically scans for changes to your project files If you save changes and recompile your class files, Jetty redeploys your webapp, and you can instantly test the changes that were just made.

Comment: Your Jetty needs to be running while you try to run your webapp on localhost.